# How to add button using layout both defined in the main.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I created the button in the main.xml file and initialized it in the activity file but I am not sure how to get the button to appear on screen using the layout defined in the xml. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class MyTasteActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");

        Button collectionBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.collectionBtn);

    }

    public void collectionBtn(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Collection was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {}
}
```

XML File:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="310px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/collectionBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="collectionBtn"
            android:text="Collection" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setContentView()` to tell Android what layout file to use for you `Activity`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xml_file_name_here);
}
```